# Upserting a dictionary with another dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Some attributes of objects in our stack are stored in JSON format. When a part of an object is edited in the front-end, the information should be updated in the back-end.

To accomplish this, I have written the following function:

```
def save_update(d1: dict, d2: dict):
    
    for k, v in d1.items():
        if k in d2:
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                d2[k].update(v)

            elif isinstance(v, list):
                d2[k].extend(v)

    d1.update(d2)

    return d1
```

The problem here is that we run the risk of extending the list with duplicates whenever. In an ideal world this should not happen, but we want to prevent side-effects before they occur. An alternative would be to change the function like so:

```
def upsert_dictionary(d1: dict, d2: dict):
    """updates d1 with the key-value pairs of d2 and
    checks for nested dicts and lists 1 deep
    """

    # loop over key-value pairs
    for k, v in d1.items():

        # if d2 contains this key we check for nested lists and dicts and perform an update
        if k in d2:
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                d2[k].update(v)

            # if the value is a list, we prevent duplicates by converting to a set
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                extended_list = d2[k] + (v)
                d2[k] = list(set(extended_list))

    d1.update(d2)

    return d1
```

This last solution seems fine, but is going to throw an exception when it is not possible to convert the contents of the list to a set. This means strict guidelines for the format is required (which goes against the point of using json in the first place) or an additional check is required

I can imagine others have tried a similar thing before, is there a better way to go about this problem?

Comment: Could you add some example of inputs and outputs? Currently I find it hard to imagine what your problem is.

Comment: How long can these lists be? Is using a set maybe premature because the membership test of a list will only bother you if those lists are long, but it works with non-hashable objects.

Comment: @user2390182 they should not be very long, it will be mostly used to store small form results. For some context: the reason we want to prevent duplicates is because such a form can be updated multiple times (e.g. for a review) or 'one form' can consists of multiple small ones for the user, but be stored as a single big form. Due to this repetition we run the risk of creating duplicate information Currently I have to manually check each script and carefully create an update function, but this is time consuming and prone to mistakes causing loss of information.

Comment: Just add the elements from one list to the other one-by-one while checking if they are in the other first. That is easy and does not concern itself with tricky things like hashability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might (unfortunately) have to iterate over the values in `v` and check for equality. Though a shortcut would be to first check if the members are hashable:

```py
from typing import Hashable, List, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def is_hashable(l1: List[T], l2: List[T]) -> bool:
    """Check if list members are hashable 
    assuming homogeneous types
    """
    return (
        (l1 and isinstance(l1[0], Hashable))
        or (l2 and isinstance(l2[0], Hashable))
    )


def upsert_dictionary(d1: dict, d2: dict):
    """updates d1 with the key-value pairs of d2 and
    checks for nested dicts and lists 1 deep
    """

    # loop over key-value pairs
    for k, v in d1.items():
        v2 = d2.get(k)

        if v2 is None:
            continue

        # if d2 contains this key we check for nested lists and dicts and perform an update
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            d2[k].update(v)

        elif isinstance(v, list) and is_hashable(v, v2):
            # use a set union here
            d2[k] = list(set(v).union(v2))
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            extended_list = [val for val in v2 if val not in v]
            extended_list.extend(v)

            d2[k] = extended_list

    d1.update(d2)

    return d1
```

Comment: You can use comparison operator chaining for the first test:  `if a is b is None`

Comment: The idea looks fine, but I'd nest the 'is_hashable' test in the 'is_instance' one so as not to call the function twice.

Comment: @Swifty ah you're right, I can just do `elif isinstance(v, list)`

Comment: @user2390182 right since `None` is a singleton

Comment: If for example `l1 = [5, [6, 7]]` then `is_hashable(l1, l2)` returns True - but clearly `l1` is unhashable there and `set(l1)` will throw.

Comment: @C.Nivs Nah, `x is y and z is y` is equivalent to `x is y is z` regardless of any properties of the involved objects. But the fact that you are using `is` in the first place stems from the singularity of `None`.

Comment: @slothrop yes, that is true. I've made an assumption that OP's json lists are homogeneous

Comment: @slothrop I've updated my solution to make that assumption more clear

Comment: That makes sense. If you like then, `is_hashable` could be a 1-liner: `return (l1 and isinstance(l1[0], Hashable)) or (l2 and isinstance(l2[0], Hashable))`

Comment: @slothrop that's a good one, I'll make an edit

Comment: This seems like a good solution! I will try this and update if any interesting behavior pops up. The lists are homogeneous, I'll add this to the question as well.